# Whole page translation at once in Vue app

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js, translate, google-translation-api

I am trying to translate my entire project made with Vue(Nuxt) using google translate API.

It is possible to translate the whole page using Default layout but I could not find a way to put back the translated result.

Is there an way to easily achieve translating entire html page at once? Instead of translating every element and put those text back to the elements.

Comment: You send text or html to Google translate API?

Comment: @BallonUra both can be done since google api can recognize html. However, I can't find a way to put back the result I got from translated result. I am trying to do something like `google.translate.TranslateElement` which just transform all the text to other languages.

Comment: What happen if you sent the parent element to google.translate.TranslateElement? The Google translate API can understand nested HTML elements?

Comment: @BallonUra It doesn't provide any customization I believe. So I can't make my own element buttons for translation.